# Print a string in console.log instead of a number

Tags: javascript, console.log, fizzbuzz

I want to print the strings: "Fizz", "Buzz" and "FizzBuzz" in `console.log` instead of the number they refer to. The point is that until now I can get both number and string, but I don't know how to overcome the number value with the string. For example, the `console.log` of the code below should be `1 2 Fizz` and not `1 2 3 Fizz`.

```js
//Define listNumber
var listNumber;

//Generate numers from 1 to 100
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  listNumber = i;
  console.log(listNumber);

  if ((listNumber % 3 == 0) && (listNumber % 5 == 0)) {
    console.log('FizzBuzz');
  } else if (listNumber % 3 == 0) {
    console.log('Fizz');
  } else if (listNumber % 5 == 0) {
    console.log('Buzz');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You log the initial value before you do your check. Simply move it to the end of the evaluation, so that if it's neither `Fizz`, `Buzz` or `FizzBuzz` it prints the actual number.

```js
//Define listNumber
var listNumber;

//Generate numers from 1 to 100
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  listNumber = i;


  if ((listNumber % 3 == 0) && (listNumber % 5 == 0)) {
    console.log('FizzBuzz');
  } else if (listNumber % 3 == 0) {
    console.log('Fizz');
  } else if (listNumber % 5 == 0) {
    console.log('Buzz');
  } else {
    console.log(listNumber);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```js
//Define listNumber
var listNumber;

//Generate numers from 1 to 100
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  listNumber = i;

  if ((listNumber % 3 == 0) && (listNumber % 5 == 0)) {
    console.log('FizzBuzz');
  } else if (listNumber % 3 == 0) {
    console.log('Fizz');
  } else if (listNumber % 5 == 0) {
    console.log('Buzz');
  } else console.log(listNumber);

}
```

I log `listNumber` only in case I haven't logged `FizzBuzz`, `Fizz` or `Buzz`.

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop you are printing the current i.
If You want the code to work you can add an else statements to it so it will only log once.

```
var listNumber;

//Generate numers from 1 to 100
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  listNumber = i;
  if ((listNumber % 3 == 0) && (listNumber % 5 == 0)) {
   console.log('FizzBuzz');
  } else if (listNumber % 3 == 0) {
   console.log('Fizz');
  } else if (listNumber % 5 == 0) {
   console.log('Buzz');
  }
  else{
   console.log(listNumber);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `else` statement in your conditions structure. In this way numbers will only be printed if all of the conditions are false.

```js
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  listNumber = i;

  if ((listNumber % 3 == 0) && (listNumber % 5 == 0)) {
    console.log('FizzBuzz');
  } else if (listNumber % 3 == 0) {
    console.log('Fizz');
  } else if (listNumber % 5 == 0) {
    console.log('Buzz');
  } else {
    console.log(listNumber);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking . Instead of printing listNumber in for loop every time place an extra else inside of if else clause and print only when its not printed "Fizz(/&)Buzz"

```js
//Define listNumber
var listNumber;

//Generate numers from 1 to 100
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  listNumber = i;
  

  if ((listNumber % 3 == 0) && (listNumber % 5 == 0)) {
    console.log('FizzBuzz');
  } else if (listNumber % 3 == 0) {
    console.log('Fizz');
  } else if (listNumber % 5 == 0) {
    console.log('Buzz');
  }
  else {
  console.log(listNumber);
  }

}
```